# Recursive CTE query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've looked at many recursive CTE examples on this site already and I've tried applying this to my own data. I seem to have a few more joins than most examples but I think I'm getting there. The problem I want help with is that I get an error saying:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

I have run the first select statement of the CTE and I've repeatedly run the second select statement (with different actual position codes) and for this employee there are six levels so I can't see why I get the error.

My one area of suspicion is that I have to apply the criteria 'relationship_type_id = 0' as this is the 'Reports To' relationship type.  I had tried making this a left outer join but they aren't allowed.  This means I don't get the top level manager using this query (i.e. the person with no manager themselves).

I've posted the code below and any help would be much appreciated.

```
WITH EmployeeHierarchy (EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, PositionCode, ReportsTo, HierarchyLevel) AS 
(
   SELECT 
      p.employee_id as EmployeeID,
      p.last_name as LastName,
      p.first_name as FirstName,
      pos.position_code as PositionCode,
      r.to_position_code as ReportsTo,
      1 as HierarchyLevel
   FROM 
       --JOIN: Personal details
       dbo.person p
   --JOIN: Employment links a person to a post (could have more than one)
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.employment e ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id
   --JOIN: details of the position held
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.position pos ON pos.position_code = e.position_code
   --JOIN: Relationships between the positions, one position reports to another position etc.
   --      There are several 'relationship types', we are only interested in relationship_type_id = 0 
   --      as this is the 'Reports to' relationship code.  Others types include 'Managed by' etc.
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.relationship r ON r.from_position_code = pos.position_code AND r.relationship_type_id = 0
   WHERE 
       --CRITERIA: Use my employee Id as a starting point for testing
       p.employee_id = '10076395'

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive step
   SELECT 
       p2.employee_id as EmployeeID,
       p2.last_name as LastName,
       p2.first_name as FirstName,
       pos2.position_code as PositionCode,
       r2.to_position_code as ReportsTo,
       eh.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
   FROM 
       dbo.person p2
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.employment e2 ON e2.employee_id = p2.employee_id
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.position pos2 ON pos2.position_code = e2.position_code
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.relationship r2 ON r2.from_position_code = pos2.position_code AND r2.relationship_type_id = 0
   --JOIN: Link this query back to the base query
   INNER JOIN 
       EmployeeHierarchy eh ON r2.from_position_code = eh.PositionCode
)
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeHierarchy
ORDER BY HierarchyLevel, LastName, FirstName
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the structure of the data but you don't use `to_position_code` in the recursive part of your query and I'm guessing this is the next level up which you want to get.

Comment: I haven't looked at your code thoroughly yet, but since this _could_ be a circular reference in your data, I suggest you post enough sample data to reproduce the issule.

Comment: Try adding `where HierarchyLevel < 3` to the recursive part of the CTE. That should let you look at a partial result so you can see where it's heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

I've moved the complex joins to a separate CTE to keep the recursive section as clean and as simple as possible. If nothing else this approach should help you pinpoint your issue.

```
; WITH employees AS (
  SELECT person.employee_id
       , person.last_name
       , person.first_name
       , position.position_code
       , relationship.to_position_code
  FROM   dbo.person
   INNER
    JOIN dbo.employment
      ON employment.employee_id = person.employee_id
   INNER
    JOIN dbo.position
      ON position.position_code = employment.position_code
   INNER
    JOIN dbo.relationship
      ON relationship.from_position_code = position.position_code
     AND relationship.relationship_type_id = 0
)
, recursive_bit AS (
  SELECT employee_id
       , last_name
       , first_name
       , position_code
       , to_position_code
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  employee_id = '10076395'

    UNION ALL

      SELECT employees.employee_id
           , employees.last_name
           , employees.first_name
           , employees.position_code
           , employees.to_position_code
      FROM   recursive_bit
       INNER
        JOIN employees
          ON employees.position_code = recursive_bit.to_position_code
)
SELECT *
FROM   recursive_bit
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try :

```
WITH EmployeeHierarchy (EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, PositionCode, ReportsTo, HierarchyLevel) AS 
(
SELECT 
    p.employee_id as EmployeeID,
    p.last_name as LastName,
    p.first_name as FirstName,
    pos.position_code as PositionCode,
    r.to_position_code as ReportsTo,
    1 as HierarchyLevel
FROM 
    --JOIN: Personal details
    dbo.person p

    --JOIN: Employment links a person to a post (could have more than one)
    INNER JOIN dbo.employment e
    ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id

    --JOIN: details of the position held
    INNER JOIN dbo.position pos 
    ON pos.position_code = e.position_code

    --JOIN: Relationships between the positions, one position reports to another position etc.
    --      There are several 'relationship types', we are only interested in relationship_type_id = 0 
    --      as this is the 'Reports to' relationship code.  Others types include 'Managed by' etc.
    INNER JOIN dbo.relationship r
    ON  r.from_position_code = pos.position_code
        and r.relationship_type_id = 0
WHERE 
    --CRITERIA: Use my employee Id as a starting point for testing
    p.employee_id = '10076395'

UNION ALL
-- Recursive step
SELECT 
    p2.employee_id as EmployeeID,
    p2.last_name as LastName,
    p2.first_name as FirstName,
    pos2.position_code as PositionCode,
    r2.to_position_code as ReportsTo,
    eh.HierarchyLevel + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
 FROM 
    dbo.person p2

    INNER JOIN dbo.employment e2
    ON e2.employee_id = p2.employee_id

    INNER JOIN dbo.position pos2 
    ON pos2.position_code = e2.position_code

    INNER JOIN dbo.relationship r2
    ON  r2.from_position_code = pos2.position_code
        and r2.relationship_type_id = 0

    --JOIN: Link this query back to the base query
    INNER JOIN EmployeeHierarchy eh 
    ON r2.from_position_code = eh.ReportsTo
)
SELECT *
FROM EmployeeHierarchy
ORDER BY HierarchyLevel, LastName, FirstName
```

Comment: Well spotted yswai1986!  Thanks, it works a treat :-)

Comment: Szymon, you were right too of course!  Thanks guys, amazingly prompt responses and this is my first ever post - I'm very impressed!